# How can I get Android Studio to work with Meteor

Tags: android, meteor, sdk

I'm running Meteor 1.4.4.2 and i'm trying to figure out how to get Android Studio to work with it. I am aware that there is a known issue with android sdk Tools 25.3.x and I have searched all over the web and seen plenty of "solutions" that simply have not worked for me. I have recently uninstalled Android Studio for like the 5th time and I now have a 25.2.3 version of sdk tools. Where can I go from here? I have the most recent version of JDK installed. I've tried downloading Android Studio and the switching out the tools folder for this older version and that got rid of my original error message in the command line (which i'm sorry I didn't save unfortunately, but it said two things. It said cordova could not find sdk tools and that there was no .gradle) but then it tried to build the app and then threw 30-50 error messages that I did not understand. My system is macOS Sierra 10.12.4

I am a true beginner in all this so thank you for your patience. Any help would be so much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you replaced the tools folder of the Android-SDK because there is templates folder is missing from the latest version and also check for the path . Did you set the path correctly for your Android platform if yes than please show your error logs that would be better to understand where is the actual problem.Thanks